# Are questions about help finding playgroups on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Suggested that 'Help me find a playgroup' be OFF-topic.

Answer (score 7):

OMG seconded. We have two generic questions in that vein right now -- [where do I post on the Web to find players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47/what-are-the-best-places-on-the-web-to-advertise-for-players) and [how do I find players overseas](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/550/gather-a-group-of-players-in-a-foreign-country). I'd suggest one more question along the lines of "what are good ways to find players in my area besides the Web," which'll get the usual advice about posting at gaming stores, try college clubs, etc. But none of the where do I find players in East Framingham stuff.

Answer (score 5):

We should direct people to existing "generic" questions on the topic - like [Where can I find other RPG players?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/where-can-i-find-other-rpg-players) - but specific ones about a given person are "too localized."

Comment: Done, so added.