# Is "shop recommendation" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Earlier today, I was wondering where a good (local) shop to buy GURPS source books was to be found. I already have an answer, but wonderde if this would be on-topic or not for RPG.SE

On one hand, it would probably benefit the hobby if people could find good, local game stores.

On the other hand, every such question would be of only limited geographic interest (an answer suitable for Haparanda, Sweden is of next-to-no interest in Blacksburg, VA, US) and possibly of limited temporal extent (a shop that was open when an answer was accepted may well have folded 2-3 years later).

I haven't seen any obvious decision as to if this is on- or off-topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is off topic because it is *too localized*, as you intuited. Similar to questions about finding local play groups - one "general" question on "how do I find play groups" is OK, but multiple ones about how do I find a play group in e.g. Haparanda is not, see [Are questions about help finding playgroups on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123/are-questions-about-help-finding-playgroups-on-topic)

One question on how do I find a local game store that will contain such gems of wisdom like "use the yellow pages and ask around, durrr" would be fine, but not localized ones.